# Formatter Function not working in Highstocks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to add the Custom X-axis values in the Highstocks, But I don't know why The x-Axis values Reflecting in the Highcharts. Here is the code that I have tried.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="check">
 </div>
```

**JS:**

```
    Highcharts.stockChart('check', {  

        rangeSelector: {
                enabled: false
            },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ["a", "b", "c"],

        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                console.log(this.value);
                return  this.value;

            }
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: {
                duration: 2000
            },
            marker:{
              enabled: false
            }
        }
    },

    xAxis:{
      animation:{
        enabled:true
       },
    },

    series: [{
        data: [5,3,4]
    }]
});
```

Here is the Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/j2Ls0gr3/

In the fiddle, you can see that Instead of categories values a,b, c its showing timestamp value.

I just want to display the Category's values. I don't know why the Formatter function not working.

Comment: Why you are using highstocks why you are not using simple line chart ??

Comment: You have an object literal with two `xAxis` properties.

Comment: it's an example . I need some highstock properties , that's why I am using Highstocks @ArsalanAkhtar

Comment: If I remove the the second xAcis object. it's showing the X-axis count. not the categories values.  http://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/d593meuh/  @Titus

Comment: I think only basic line chart will fulfill your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that **xAxis.categories** and **xAxis.type** (to set another type) features don't exist in the Highstock documentation.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis

However, you can use the **label.formatter** callback to find the position of the ticks in the globally defined array and return it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ak850jLu/

```
var xAxisCategories = ['a', 'b', 'c']

Highcharts.stockChart('check', {

  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {

        return xAxisCategories[this.value];
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [5, 3, 4]
  }]
});
```

Comment: That's great bot the labels in navigators are not change as per the X-axis

Comment: You need to do the same for the navigator.xAxis. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c3s8hdr4/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.xAxis